# How much current is significant?

Tags: power

I have a box that specifies 5V and 2.5A.
I have a plug that gives 5V and 2.0A.

If I hook the two together will I see the explosion? What are the chances that my box will work?

Comment: Please explain the down-votes so I can fix my question.

Comment: Uhm... *maybe* it's the missing details? Your "box"? What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your power supply will struggle to cope but what actually happens will depend on its exact design - it may:

- Just not work
- Overheat
- Shut down after a while
- Blow an internal fuse
- Provide limited current to your device, which may affect its operation
- Just about work but get hotter than normal

If it were my setup I'd be looking for another power unit